# Heroku and MySQLi Custom Buildpack

Tags: mysql, heroku

I am in the process of trying to get mysqli on heroku to run my php application.  I know this can be done using custom buildpacks, but I am stuck.

I have forked the canned heroku php buildpack and have started digging through that and I think I need to make an adjustment to the 'bin/compile' file.

Do I need to host and compile my own php package similar to how americastestkitchen does or is there something I am missing beside the detect, compile, and release files?

My Forked Buildpack: https://github.com/travstoll/heroku-buildpack-php

Similar Project: https://github.com/Americastestkitchen/heroku-wordpress-php/

Thanks in advance for pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question...

I am needing to build, compile and host my own custom php version for this to work and have mysqli enabled.  The default php buildpack for heroku does not have the mysqli extension installed, but it can be done by:

-Downloading the php source for the version you want.
-Configuring the extensions including mysqli (--with-mysqli) and then making the php version
-recompiling into a tarball and then hosting on s3

You can then use the s3 link as the php version link in the compile file and mysqli will be enabled.

**EDIT:**  As of Today, 4/29/2014, Heroku Natively supports MySQLi and PHP